# Filter by answered/unanswered on user profile?

Tags: discussion

At the moment when you go onto your user profile > questions, you can sort by newest, votes, views etc. I think it would be really handy to have a filter for answered or unanswered.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already implemented in a round-about way. See the [Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=) for more info, but search queries like this will get you what you're looking for:

- [user:me is:question answers:0](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:9568%20is:question%20answers:0&submit=search) will get your unanswered questions
- [user:me is:question answers:1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:9568%20is:question%20answers:1) will get your answered questions

You could also extend it to find questions with an accepted answer:

- [user:me is:question hasaccepted:1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:9568%20is:question%20hasaccepted:1&submit=search)

There are loads of options, definitely worth a play around :)